# How to check if a row in an excel table has certain values in it using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

As the title states I have a table in excel and I want to check if a row in that table contains certain values in it. For example: Table1 has

```
pid | F_Name | L_Name

0   | Bob    | Stoops

1   |  Mike  | Gundy

2   | Dabo   | Swinney
```

And I want my script to search pid = 0, and L_Name = Stoops, and I want it to return what row in excel that is located.

Also If I were to search pid = 2, and F_Name = Bob and essentially do nothing.

All I can find is the function 'find' when giving it a range object, but I need something a little more than just that. Not sure how to do multiple conditions for a search in vba and return the row.

Thanks and all help is appreciated !

Comment: Is your file actually comma separated? You could concat your columns and search for the full string match (`0Stoops`) instead of searching for `0` and then `Stoops`

Comment: No it's not. Mb for not making that clear. It's an excel table and each columns has a header

Comment: You could also loop using nested condition testing - or, if there is always 1 match, you could just filter and work with the visible rows

Comment: there's no guarantee of a match, so you suggest just doing nested ifs?

Comment: What do you want to do when you find the match?

Comment: highlight the first column of that row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to update a few things here

- Update sheet name in 2nd line
- Find a more systematic way to assign values to `pid` and `L_Name` variables. *InputBox?*
- Create your action statement when your criteria is matched. Note that `i` denotes the row you are on

---

```
Sub Nest()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim i As Long
Dim pid As String      'If always # change to Long and change "0" to 0 below
Dim L_Name As String

pid = "0"
L_Name = "Stoops"

For i = 2 To ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If ws.Range("A" & i) = pid And ws.Range("C" & i) = L_Name Then
        'Do what when your criteria is matched?
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

---

*I also assumed your data covers columns A:C so you will need to adjust this as well to reflect your accurate data*

Comment: Thank you for the help!
Quick question, how would this scale for a table that has say ~10k rows? Would it still be fast even though it's going throw every single one? What if most of those entries would fail on the first condition?

Comment: This is set up to loop through every row that you have on `column a`. I would test this on a small data set for now. (Convert to maybe 100 rows to test). Get it working and then drop in your full data. How to speed this up is a separate issue and you should research that separately or raise a new question. The most common first step is to turn screenupdating off and back on before ending sub. Keep the focus here on your initial question.

Comment: What you end up doing inside the loop will have a lot of impact on how long this will take. So, that is something that you can just test and answer yourself. I have no idea how long it will take